# Unable to activate Memory Integrity in Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, memory, hyper-v

I am trying to enable Memory Integrity on my Windows 10 Pro v1809 but I receive the following error:

```
Memory integrity can't be started. There may be an incompatibility on your device.
```

I have checked the requirements and it looks like I should be fine.
I have an i7 5820K on an Asus X99-A mobo with a TPM 2.0. Secure boot, Hyper-V and Bitlocker are enabled.

The error does not offer any details.
Any ideas on what could be incompatible?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/357757/what-are-core-isolation-and-memory-integrity-in-windows-10/ suggests incompatability with a lot of drives as well as virtualization software. Are you virtualizing?

Comment: I have VirtualBox installed but it's not in use.. shall I try uninstalling it?

Comment: I uninstalled it, rebooted but I still get that message

Comment: VirtualBox and Hyper-V are _both_ virtualization.